# Build a Simple Android App > Basic Android Programming > Red Rs & Missing Resource Tag

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

building my first Android App.  I've been following a tutorial but it has left me with 2 issues detailed below(possibly because they are using an older version of AS in the tutorials).  The 2 issues might very well just be 1 issues, as if often the case.  But since I'm still getting my feet wet with Android, Android Studio, Gradle, etc...I'm a little unsure of where or how to go about things.  As you will see below, I've included a great amount of detail.  Much of it is probably unneeded, but this might provide a lesson in debugging.

### Question 1: Why are my **Rs** red & how can I change this?

#### Two examples:

- setContentView(**R**.layout.activity_fun_facts);
- findViewById(**R**.id.factTextView);

#### FunFactsActivity.java

```js
package com.craigreedwilliams.funfacts;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FunFactsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);

        // Declare our View variables and assign the the Views from the layout file
        final TextView factLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextView);
        Button showFactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showFactButton);
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // The button was clicked, so update the fact label with a new fact
                String fact = "Ostriches can run faster than horses.";
                factLabel.setText(fact);

            }
        };
        showFactButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fun_facts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### Question 2: When I changed 'Hello World' to 'Did you know?' I did not get a warning as the video suggested, but in fact, got any error. How do I apply the proper resource tag?(video doesn't help here)##

**Pic:** http://screencast.com/t/hTv6moboWA

**Pic:** http://screencast.com/t/9cjVMaZA

#### activity_fun_facts.xml

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".FunFactsActivity"
    android:background="#ff51b46d">

    <TextView android:text="Did you Know?" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#80ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/factTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show another fun fact."
        android:id="@+id/showFactButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Also Included 1: Event Log

```js
4:42:23 PM Gradle build finished in 34 sec
4:46:45 PM Gradle build finished in 14 sec
4:48:08 PM Throwable: Icon cannot be found in '/icons/versions/null_32.png', aClass='class icons.AndroidIcons'
6:07:56 PM Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 9 sec
12:19:55 AM Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 21 sec
12:20:29 AM Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 3 sec
1:32:08 AM Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 17 sec
1:32:31 AM Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 2 sec
```

### Also Included 2: Messages Gradle Build

```js
C:\Users\Reed\AndroidStudioProjects\FunFacts\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_fun_facts.xml

Error:(11, 21) Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Reed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Information:BUILD FAILED

Information:Total time: 2.275 secs

Information:2 errors

Information:0 warnings
```

### Also Included 3: Gradle Console

```js
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Resource id cannot be an empty string (at \u0027id\u0027 with value \u0027@+id/\u0027).","sourcePath":"C:\\Users\\Reed\\AndroidStudioProjects\\FunFacts\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_fun_facts.xml","position":{"startLine":11,"startColumn":21,"startOffset":662,"endColumn":26,"endOffset":667},"original":""}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Reed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.275 secs
```

Comment: Please post separate questions individually. Doing so helps making finding answers easier for subsequent Stack Overflow users, as well as making it more likely that you will obtain a helpful answer.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you included the actual stack trace that lists the errors you encountered and point out for us the lines in your code to which those errors point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an error 
Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/')

```
     <TextView android:text="Did you Know?" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#80ffffff" />
```

it should be

```
    android:id="@+id/some_name_here"
```

If you dont want to use the text view any where in your java code you can remove the whole android:id="@+id" i.e you dont have to assign an id

Comment: You are welcome. Follow the tutorial and also  check out developer.android.com